# booting files in a usb

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I need to boot my USB which contains a utility program I have written. How can I make my USB bootable?

Comment: What OS would this be for ?

Comment: What do you want to boot into? Linux? Windows? BartPE? Are you writing your own OS and trying to test it from a pen drive? we need more info.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make a USB drive bootable, but to run your utility you will want to boot into an operating system of some sort.  Try these guides:

- [Run Windows XP from a flash drive](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5928902.html)
- [Run Linux from a flash drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) (instructions for various distros)

If you're using a computer with an operating system already installed, and you just want your utility to start when you instert the usb key, what you need is Autorun:

- [Autorun anything off of a usb key](http://www.instructables.com/id/Autorun-anything-off-of-a-usb-key/)

Comment: The last link pertains only to Windows.

Comment: Yes.  The equivilent does not really exist in Linux.  The question does not give much detail unfortunately